# Could not add android platform to cordova project from cordova CLI

Tags: cordova

I am having problems in adding android platform to my cordova project. All things that are required have been installed. I have jdk,sdk for android, npm, git and cordova. All have latest version as of 06/14/2017. I am able to create cordova project with the command `cordova create myapp`.

But after the app is successfully created and when I run `cordova platform add android` from within the myapp folder I get an error. I have tried everything but could not get it done. I have already set ANDROID_HOME, added Android SDK tools and platform-tools directories to **PATH**, used `--nofetch` but to no avail.

Below is the command prompt error message after I run my command `cordova platform add android`

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2 

Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2 

Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect. Check your connection and platform name/version/URL. 

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Error output: npm ERR! shasum check failed for
C:\Users\PARAS~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3048-83f48a6f\registry.npmjs.org\cordova-android\-\cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz

npm ERR! Expected: 249f21b6ce5f1f1c847a7ab83b16909dbed5aa28 

npm ERR! Actual: ace33a120d0172a175c73e708f0552cc205731b0 

npm ERR! From: http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 

npm ERR! C:\Users\paras.sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-14T11_09_17_075Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try:  'cordova platform add android@latest'

Comment: Exactly same result with "cordova platform add android@latest" also

Answer (score 3):

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2
npm ERR! Expected: 249f21b6ce5f1f1c847a7ab83b16909dbed5aa28  
npm ERR! Actual: ace33a120d0172a175c73e708f0552cc205731b0 
From: http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz
```

I have experienced the above error before.

This error occurs when the downloaded `cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz` is **incomplete or currupt**. Or `npm` is looking for a **lower version 6.2.2.**

`npm` is expecting the hash digest (MD5 or SHA1) `249f21b6ce5f1f1c847a7ab83b16909dbed5aa28` for the downloaded file while adding the android platform. 
But your downloaded file has `ace33a120d0172a175c73e708f0552cc205731b0`.

**Quick Fix -**

- **DELETE** the downloaded file **cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz** or folder **npm-304 8-83f48a6f** in -

  ```
  C:\Users\PARAS~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-304 8-83f48a6f\registry.npmjs.org\cordova-android-\cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz
  ```
- And do `cordova platform add android` again. npm will redownload the required file.

You can also download it **manually** **(7.7 MB)** from **[here](http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz)** and place it in the same folder and then run the command.

Comment: It didnt work. I ran the command 'cordova platform add android' again after deleting C:\Users\PARAS~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-304 8-83f48a6f\registry.npmjs.org\cordova-android-\cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz but the result is same as mentioned in the question. I also tried downloading the file but it is giving some warning reagarding data leak.

Comment: did you check the versions? 6.2.2 vs 6.2.3. You might want **6.2.2**. Also try updating cordova using `sudo npm update -g cordova`. Recent version is 7.0.1.

Comment: I got exactly the same result with "cordova platform add android~6.2.2" also.

Comment: Okay.  Clear that `Temp` folder totally, Update `cordova` and try once. The reason behind the error is same. I am pretty sure. May be we aren't hitting it the right way. Just missing something.

Comment: This didnt help either. same result